# UITableView with automatic dimension do no display cells properly. Always the LAST label within that cell is sometimes broken

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

Simple case:

Some of my cells are displayed randomly with proper way or not:

- this is a good way:

[image]

- this is not a good way.

[image]

What it depends on, and how to fix it?

Interesting thing:

I added at the end another label:

and now that last label sometimes is not displayed properly. But my previous label now is correct **every time**. What is going on?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure:

1. Lines is set to `0`
2. Line Breaks is set to `Character Wrap`

If your problem still not solved set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

Comment: lines is set to 0, and line breaks to `Character Wrap`. Still the same.

Comment: There is no code, everything with layout is set within Storyboard.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk visit the githud address i wrote , you may find the resolution..

Comment: No, i do not like the third party libraries for such things. But thanks... any other ideas?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Preferred WIdth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87876/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-destiny).

Comment: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` helped:)

Answer (score 0):

After a big digging, I have found the answer. `Automatic dimension` is not working well for some `UILabel` if that label is aligned with different label by **top edges** or **bottom edges**. If you get in such bug, just make sure that you do not have such alignment.